# Reading values into a 2d array for C++?

Tags: c++

Say that I have array MatrixA which is 2x3 and is filled to 0.  How do I set up my loop so that values would be read into it but if the user only enters 3 values, the remaining 3 in MatrixA are 0?

Edit:

```
const int Q = 2;
const int S = 3;
int matrixA[Q][S] = {0};
for(int i = 0; i < Q; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < S; j++){
            cin >> matA[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know how to access them? And show your current code.

Comment: Your loop is fine to me.

Comment: How will you know that the user ended entering values???

Comment: That is part that is confusing me Rashad.

Comment: You can use end of file. (Thats f6 or ctrl+z). If the input is end of file stop scanning. :)

Comment: @herohuyongtao i think he wants to fill the array until the user inputs some kind of invalid input and then within the __same__ loop initialize the rest of the array to `0`s

Comment: Do you mean if the user doesn't enter input for 3 rows, to set the values for that row to 0s?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize array MatrixA with 0s and then accept values from user. Code would be something like below:

```
int iOuter = 0;
int iInner = 0;
for (iOuter = 0; i <2; iOuter++)
   for (iInner = 0; i < 3; iInner++)
   {
      MatrixA[iOuter][iInner] = 0;
      cin >> MatrixA[iOuter][iInner];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Id rather you have code for me to work off of for my answer but assuming your question and statement I will say this. Have a loop in which counts the amount of times the user inputs a number. When the user enters three numbers; Initialize a row variable in which takes the value of 2. Then loop it based on the amount of times the user imputed numbers with a for loop or any other method you choose.

Also to answer your question about the remaining 3 numbers I have provided a link below about the array uninitialized indexes

[Why is int array not initialized to zeros in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812687/why-is-int-array-not-initialized-to-zeros-in-c)?

Answer (score 0):

```
const int Q = 2;
const int S = 3;
int flag = 0;
int matrixA[Q][S] = {0};
for(int i = 0; i < Q; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < S; j++){
        matA[i][j] = 0;
    }
 }

for(int i = 0; i < Q; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < S; j++){
        if(getline(cin, matA[i][j])){

        }
        else{
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1){
        break;
    }
}
```

Let me know if that helps.. :)